# Remove html hyper links from URL in Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook

I want to send email from backend php and HTML with links but does not want to use as hyperlink. I want to display those links as normal email text. Here is my working sample html.

```html
<body>
<p>http://www.google.com</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found myself for this answer

```
    <a href='#' style="text-tecoration:none; color:#000; cursor:defualt">
     http://www.google.com</a>
```

Its work for me in Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's an option for this in outlook Under Compose messages, --> Editor Options. here's try this article and see if it helps [Stop text from turning into a hyperlink](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Stop-text-from-turning-into-a-hyperlink-f361cb96-02e4-40bb-b39c-0ef5e2faac90)

Comment: Sorry i need to remove hyperlinks in email send to other users. Is there anyway to remove in html.?

Comment: can you explain please: 
1- you want to remove the hyperlink property of links in emails you received form others or 
2- you want to prevent outlook from creating them?

Comment: I sending emails from backend php. For that i am using html template as email. From that HTML i want to change the hyperlinks as normal text.